# Kicad telling me to connect pads together when I feel it's incorrect

Tags: power-electronics, 12v, fuses, trace, fuse-holders

Hey all I am wondering if this is the correct way to trace a fuse holder on my pcb. I would imagine that the top 2 pads connected to each other and the bottom 2 pads connected to each other. Running a trace from the bottom to the top would cause it to bypass the fuse if I took it out, right? That's what the fuse would do - connect the bottom pads to the top pads to complete the circuit?

Or does it go from the top left pad to the bottom left pad. Then the top right pad to the bottom right pad then the 2 bottom pads connected together but not the top?

[image]
[image]

As suggested by vir it seems to work now:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the corresponding schematic? It seems like the netlist *does* show both sides of the fuse on the same net (which would be a schematic error in that case), and the layout/LVS tool is diligently following that netlist, but we'd need to see the schematic to be sure.

Comment: @nanofarad I've updated my OP with the schematic.

Comment: Although you wrote that it's working now, your still having the same net, +12 V, on both sides. Like your last 555 question, you seem to be confused about what it means to connect two nodes.

Comment: Also, there now seem to be two fuse symbols stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the same net "+12V" on both sides so Kicad thinks they should be connected. Name one "+12Vin" or "Fused_12V" or something like that and the problem should go away.

Comment: Yep that seems to have stopped kicad from trying to map to the wrong things. Thanks vir!